# Cleaner way to pass state variables and methods to child components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

Beginner to React, I have multiple state variables:

```
function ParentComp(){
      const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("")
      const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("")
      const [address, setAddress] = useState("")

      return <p>Bonjour</p>
}
```

Of course I can pass them to the child components like this:

```
<ChildComponent firstName = {firstName} setFirstName = {setFirstName}
                lastName = {lastName} setLastName = {setLastName}
                address = {address} setAddress = {setAddress}/>
```

But I have many more state variables, and actually I want to pass them to the child of the ChildComponent. Is there a way to wrap them in a array or object somehow? I googled and found "context api" but I'd like a more beginner friendly solution.

Comment: You could try setting the state as an object `const [data, setData] = useState({ firstName: '', lastName: '',})` and then pass prop as `<Child {...data} />`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to keep them as separate states

```
<ChildComponent {
  ...{
      firstName, 
      lastName, 
      address, 
      setFirstName, 
      setLastName, 
      setAddress
   }
} />
```

Otherwise, you coud use `useReducer` for easier updates to the state and you will get a single object with all states and one update action.